# Terminal: Expand list of similar filename shortcut

Tags: command-line, bash, shortcut-keys

I remember reading a trick in a stackoverflow comment somewhere for getting a list of filenames in the terminal, but I can't exactly remember it.

If you have a bunch of files like:

```
foo-a.txt
foo-b.txt
foo-c.txt
```

There is a trick that goes something along the lines of:

1. type `cat foo-*`
2. Press something like `tab`, `backspace`, `esc` (this does not work, but is the step I want to know)
3. The command line should now have `cat foo-a foo-b foo-c`

Note that is is different to the basic tab completion which shows a list of filenames below the command. This will put all the filenames in the command input so that pressing "enter" will execute cat with all the files.

Can anyone enlighten me?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. Type `cat foo-*`
2. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd> then <kbd>*</kbd> (asterisk/star) to expand the glob

   - If that doesn't work, run `bind -p | grep glob-expand-word` and check if it says `"\C-x*": glob-expand-word`. If not, you can set it:

     ```
     bind '"\C-x*": glob-expand-word'
     ```
3. The command line should now be `cat foo-a.txt foo-b.txt foo-c.txt`

---

#### [`glob-expand-word`](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Miscellaneous-Commands.html) vs [`insert-completions`](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Commands-For-Completion.html)

[OP's answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1115199/301745) is about `insert-completions` (<kbd>Esc</kbd>, <kbd>*</kbd> or <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>*</kbd>), which is similar but different to `glob-expand-word`:

- `glob-expand-word` expands filename globs.
- `insert-completions` inserts all the possible completions that pressing <kbd>Tab</kbd> would show.

So that means you can also use `insert-completions` for things besides filenames, like options. For example type `ls --f`, press <kbd>Esc</kbd>, <kbd>*</kbd>, and you will get `ls --file-type --format=`, though I'm not sure how useful that is.

And that means that it behaves differently when expanding globs. For example if you type `cat foo-*` and press <kbd>Esc</kbd>, <kbd>*</kbd>, it will expand to only the first completion: `cat foo-a.txt`.

Comment: Thanks, that it! Btw: You can also use esc instead of ctr+x

Comment: @mdsimmo `Esc`, `*` is a different function actually. I just checked `bind -p | grep '\\e\*'` and it says `"\e*": insert-completions`. I'm not clear on the exact difference, but if you type `cat *` then press `Esc`, `*`, it will expand to just the first matching item.

Answer (score 2):

I found the original comment [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/24630/whats-the-best-way-to-join-files-again-after-splitting-them#comment33047_24630). (Can someone with more points upvote him for me? :P)

The sequence is:

- Type `cat foo-`
- Press <kbd>esc</kbd>
- Press <kbd>*</kbd> (asterisk)

The same sequence seems to work with any program (not just `cat`)

Comment: Upvoted the comment per request :p (BTW, worth noting that comment upvotes don't count towards reputation points)

Comment: Alt+* also works (Alt+Shift+8 on a US keyboard). And in general any terminal shortcut that uses Esc, *key* can also be typed as Alt + *key*.